# Nested IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have one large IEnumerable that I want to split into several.

```
// I want to do this

    public A Method1(B b)
    {
      return Method2(b);
    }
```

Ok my code
// switcher method that should delegate the work

```
public IEnumerable<BufTrade> Split(BufTrade bufRecord)
{
  switch(someFlag)
 {
   case "A":

     // does not compile
     return Impl1(bufTrade);

     // does not compile
     yield return Impl1(bufTrade);
 }
}

// implements for type A    
public IEnumerable<BufTrade> Impl1(BufTrade bufRecord)
{
 yield return trade1;
 yield return trade2;

 // etc
}
```

Comment: I what sense is this IEnumerable nested?

Comment: What is `BufTrade`? How does `Impl1` compile? you return an `IEnumerable<int>` for an `IEnumerable<BufTrade>`.

Comment: It would help if you included the compile time errors that each of your attempts generate. You may find them informative.

Comment: @Dejan: In the sense that the enumerator function `Split` calls another enumerator function `Impl1`

Comment: `Method1` does nothing as far as I can see.

Comment: Have you considered using `.Where( (x)=> x.Flag=="A")` instead?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to do, but since `Impl1` returns an `IEnumerable<BufTrade>` and `Split` also returns the same, you need to loop over the returned values from `Impl1` in `Split` and `yield return` each one:

```
// in Split:
foreach (var i in Impl1(bufRecord))
{
    yield return i;
}
```

It's a rather awkward bit of code, but that's what you need to do if you want to use `yield return` in this situation. In other words, you want `Split` to be an enumerator function.

Your attempt to just:

```
return Impl1(bufTrade);
```

Isn't going to work (with the code you provided) because not all paths return a value. Also note that you can't mix `yield return` and `return`. You either have an enumerator function that uses `yield return` or you have a regular function that just uses `return`

Comment: return Impl1(bufTrade) will not compile because Impl1 returns IEnumerable<bufTrade> and bufTrade is expected

Comment: @CaptainComic: Of course it would compile. `Impl1` returns `IEnumerable<bufTrade>` and `Split` returns an `IEnumerable<bufTrade>` it *won't* work with a `yield return` (which would need to return a `bufTrade`, but it would work fine as a regular `return` (the not all code paths returning a value not withstanding). It would make `Split` just a regular function instead of an enumerator.